# Kernel 5.5 released - when it will be included into distribution updates?

Tags: kernel, updates

https://kernelnewbies.org/ informed 30.1.2020 about Linux_5.5 realease on January 26, 2020. How long does it take approximately to include a new kernel into update packages of different Linux distributions ?

Comment: You can expect it to have in Ubuntu 20.04, but not in the older releases.

Comment: 20.04 has been using the 5.4 awhile now,   Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with HWE enabled will eventually use the 20.04 kernel, but not until 18.04.5 is reached (18.04.2 was 18.10 stack, 18.04.3 was 19.04, 18.04.4 uses 19.10 stack, 18.04.5 uses 20.04's stack) so it's well behind to ensure stability; likewise offers to upgrade to 20.04 aren't offered for 18.04 users until 20.04.1's release..)   We are only approaching the official release of 18.04.4 (ie. 19.10 stack for 18.04)

Comment: Thank you very much for info.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE Ubuntu 20.04 will ship with 5. 4

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/02/ubuntu-20-04-kernel-5-4-lts

---

The plan is to release Ubuntu 20.04 with the 5.5 kernel. The 5.4 kernel has already been confirmed but the release of the 5.5 kernel is inside the possible window for the 20.04 release. Kernel 5.6 is likely to arrive too late.

Some sources:  [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-20.04-Adds-WireGuard)

> While WireGuard was merged into Linux 5.6, the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS release is currently tracking Linux 5.4 and for the April release is likely to be shipping with Linux 5.5 as the 5.6 release will be cutting it too close. But Ubuntu 20.04's kernel has now back-ported WireGuard.

[OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/ubuntu-20-04-release-features):

> Kernel Freeze: April 9, 2020
>
> Other planned changes to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS include:
>
> - GNOME 3.36
> - Linux Kernel 5.5 (or newer)
> - Improved ZFS install support

===

As I like to live dangerously. 20.04 currently installs:

```
$ uname -a
Linux schijfwereld 5.4.0-12-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 21 15:12:29 
UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 20.04 has been using the 5.4 awhile now, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with HWE enabled will eventually use the 20.04 kernel, but not until 18.04.5 is reached (for ISOs, installed systems get it a little earlier).

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 was 18.10 stack,
- Ubuntu 18.04.3 was 19.04 stack,
- Ubuntu 18.04.4 uses 19.10 stack,
- Ubuntu 18.04.5 uses 20.04's stack (the last stack upgrade for 18.04)

HWE for prior LTS is behind to ensure stability; likewise the offer to upgrade to 20.04 isn't offered for 18.04 users until 20.04.1's release ensuring stability for users.

We are only approaching the official release of 18.04.4 (ie. 19.10 stack for 18.04), so 18.04.5 is still awhile into the future.

*Refer @Rinzwind's answer for details on 20.04*

Comment: This is insightful, where can I find more information about the point releases and what they mean for Ubuntu?

Comment: For details on HWE see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack   The point releases mean ISO are released; 18.04.4 has been released now, the currently bionic daily is 18.04.5 now; focal is still a daily (ie. it'll become 20.04 on release; and the beta is any daily after a set date).